# Python, как работает протокол итерации для типа Dict в старой и новой версии?

Tags: python, циклы, for, while

В книге вычитал что в старых версиях Python чтобы пройтись по ключам словаря, необходимо было сделать следующее:

```
for key in D.keys():
   print(key)
```

В новой версии:

```
for key in D:
   print(key)
```

В книге написано о том, что тип Dict в новой версии стал итерируемым объектом (т.е. он имеет методы **iter** для создания объекта итератора, и **next** для прохода по нему. Но мне не ясно как цикл for работает со старой версией, если в новой версии он (цикл) вызывает метод **iter**() непосредственно у объекта словаря, то в старой версии у "объекта ключей словаря?!" D.keys() ??

т.е. `D.__iter__() == D.keys().__iter__() ??`

// объект dict стал итерируемым объектом в Python 2.X (до того как он им стал приходилось вызывать метод keys объекта dict)

Comment: В старых версиях питона «объект ключей словаря» это самый обыкновенный список. У вас же наверное не должна вызывать вопросов возможность пройтись циклом по списку?)

Comment: Укажите в вопросе, что вы подразумеваете под "старой" и "новой" версией Python. Может вы про Python 1.5 спрашиваете.

Comment: @andreymal А у вас не созревает мысль о том как цикл проходит по списку? этот вопрос на более углубленном уровне.

Comment: @insolor "Правил, вообще версия не имеет значения, это тот момент, когда объект словаря стал итерируемым

Comment: @Alegro у списка есть метод `__iter__`, который возвращает объект `list_iterator`, который имеет метод `__next__`, который собственно и возвращает элементы списка поштучно (где-то внутри объекта `list_iterator` хранится [ссылка на список и номер текущего индекса](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9652900969df77b1ac245595419431df19296af9/Objects/listobject.c#L3187-L3188), чтобы метод `__next__` понимал, какой именно следующий элемент нужно возвращать)

Comment: @andreymal Тогда о каком может быть понятии "сохранение памяти" когда в программу выгружены и сам список и объект итератора который ссылается на список? Как я читал - объект итератора не выгружает все данные в программу. И как тогда работает файловый объект, он не такой-же как список

Comment: @Alegro о каком «сохранении памяти» речь и о каком «выгружении» речь? А итератор файлового объекта просто читает файл по строкам, пока файл не кончится

Comment: С файлами я понял, они не загружаются в память "как я понял кэш программы (в книге просто не написано в какую память именно)" , но в случае со списком он сначала должен быть объявлен как обычный список. т.е.  файловый итератор загружает строку за строкой из внешнего файла, а список изначально имеется в памяти полностью, что не экономит место?!!

Comment: @andreymal Вообще вопрос немного не о том, мне лишь интересно как протокол итерации работал до того как объект словаря стал итерируемым, т..е. на чем цикл for вызывал метод  iter и next

Comment: @Alegro очевидно, список должен быть заранее создан, иначе вы не сможете итерироваться по списку, который не существует :)

Comment: В старых питонах `D.keys()` возвращал обычный список (создаваемый в памяти полностью, да). В новых питонах `D.keys()` возвращает не список, а объект `dict_keys` (я не разбирался, как он устроен, но, вероятно, он как-то экономит память). У него есть метод `__iter__` который возвращает объект `dict_keyiterator`, у которого есть метод `__next__` и который собственно используется в цикле for. У самого́ словаря тоже есть метод `__iter__`, который возвращает такое же объект `dict_keyiterator`, поэтому в новых питонах циклы `for key in D:` и `for key in D.keys():` функционально ничем не отличаются

Comment: Я уже немного путаюсь, но вроде разложил всю информацию по полочкам. В случае с файловым объектом цикл for применяет "неполный протокол итерации т.к. файловый объект изначально - объект итератора" и цикл к нему применяет только метод next, но в случае с объектом словаря приходится применять "полную итерацию", проходить путь  итерируемый объект -> объект итератора. с помощью метода iter, а далее проходить по объекту итератора который ссылается на итерируемый "исходный" объект.  Если в старой версии объект/список dict_keys также был итерируемым объектом (имел метод iter), то вопрос исчерпан.

Comment: @Alegro вы что-то слишком переусложняете, вводя странные термины вроде «неполного протокола итерации». Файловые объекты имеют такой же метод `__iter__` как и у всех, просто он возвращает тот же самый файловый объект. В старой версии питона (под «старой» я имею в виду 2.7) объекта dict_keys вообще не было, вместо него был обычный список (который таки является итерируемым объектом с методом `__iter__`)